# Display value from controller based on two dropdown selection on the view(when select both of them at the same time). MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

On the product output insert page, when user select from two dropdown lists(depoId and materialId) at the same time, I would like to display the stock quantity (stockAmount) of the product with the help of material id and the depot id. I do not know how I display on the view part and how I write based on two dropdownlist selection.

Create.cshtml

```
@model StockControl.Models.EntityFramework.OutgoingProduct

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.materialId, "Material Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("materialId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.materialId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depoId, "Product Outlet", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("depoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.depoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.chosen').chosen();
        });

      $("#materialId", "#depoId").change( function (event) {
      var materialId = $(this).val(); 
      var depoId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetStock", "OutgoingProduct")",
            data: { id : materialId, id: depoId },
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
            document.write(model.stockAmount);
            $("#divPartialView").html( data );
            }
            });
            });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ajax to send these id to controller

import jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

listen the select change event and send data to controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#depoId').change(function () { sendDataByAjax(); });            
    })

    function sendDataByAjax() {
        // make sure two dropdownlists have selected option
        var materialId= $('#materialId option:selected').val();
        var depoId= $('#depoIdoption:selected').val();

        if (!materialId || !depoId) {
            // one of dropdownlist doesn't select an option yet
        }

        var DTO = {
        'materialId': materialId,
        'depoId': depoId
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetStock", "OutgoingProduct")",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                // append data into your target part of view
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```